# How to use C constructor in windows? does the MSVC compiler provides one?

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc

In GCC compiler We can use the following code to simulate a constructor:

```
    __attribute((constructor)) void ctor(){
        printf("hello, ctor.\n");
    }
    int main(int, char** argv){
        printf("hello, main.\n");
    }
```

In Linux using gcc, the result is:

```
    hello, ctor.        
    hello, main.
```

The technology is specific to gcc compiler, does MSVC provide the similar functionality?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No Google, no cry? http://google.com/search?q=msvc+attribute+constructor

Comment: @H2CO3 What's the point of this? A portable way to achieve the same would be to use a global `static int dummy = myconstructorfunc();` which would also be called before main. Or does this achieve something different?

Comment: @Devolus IDK, ask OP. I rarely use compiler-specific features.

Comment: good, I use VC + c + conductor to as google, but find nothing useful! You help me a lot!

Comment: I just tested this, apparently it works only when compiled as C++. After compiling it as C, I also get an error, so you probably have to use this compiler specific feature nevertheless.